# Will gasket makers generally work on vertical surfaces?

Tags: gasket-maker

I need to make a gasket on a vertical surface (differential cover on back end of a tractor). Are most gasket makers thick enough to be applied this way, or will they drip?

If some will drip, are there any meant for vertical applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, I've never seen any gasket maker slip or drip. It just doesn't happen. You need to find the right gasket maker for the application if you want it to work right. [This answer I wrote a while back](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/18454/4152) may help you with what exactly you might need.

Comment: Great, thanks, that's what I guessed, but I'm doing this work way out in the bush so I didn't want to end up out there with something that doesn't work for me. Appreciate the other answer, super informative.